# Why and how to fix an async function not calling a setTimeout callback? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, callback, settimeout

I have this code:

```
let getNombre1 = async() => 'A';
let getNombre3 = () => new Promise((resolve, response) => resolve('A'));
let llamada1 = getNombre1().then(t => console.log(t)) //return A
let llamada3 = getNombre3().then(t => console.log(t)) //return A

let getNombre2 = async() => setTimeout(() => 'B', 3000);
let getNombre4 = () => new Promise((resolve, response) => (setTimeout(() => resolve('B'), 3000)))

let llamada2 = getNombre2().then(t => console.log(t)) //return print setTimeout instance
let llamada4 = getNombre4().then(t => console.log(t)) //return B
```

My question is: Why doesn't "llamada2", which is essentially the same as "llamada1", return what is "llamada4", which is essentially the same as "llamada3"?

Comment: `llamada2` is not "essentially the same" as `llamada1`, since it calls the broken `getNombre2` instead of `getNombre1`.

Comment: Consider `let getNombre5 = () => new Promise(resolve => { resolve(setTimeout(() => 'B', 3000)); })`. Can you tell why this doesn't work?

Comment: Well...  `let getNombre5 = () => new Promise(resolve => { resolve(setTimeout(() => 'B', 3000)); }) `
It does not return anything, because the function is simply assigned to the variable, it is never executed
And if i run it: `getNombre5()` execute timeout of 3 seconds and nothing returns.

Comment: The question is: why is getName2 broken?

Comment: because it does exactly the same thing as `getNombre5`